# Is there any difference between "one other" and 'another'?

Tags: difference

I'm wondering if there is any difference between "one other" and 'another'.

E.g.

> 1. There's **one other** person I'd like you to meet.
> 2. There's **another** person I'd like you to meet.

I feel that "one other" might put more emphasis? Is there any difference indeed? Or they are completely interchangeable?

Comment: Mostly no difference, except, maybe, that after introducing someone to 'one other' person, you can't introduce them to anyone else without contradicting yourself, whereas if you had said 'another', you can.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Then that seems to be a real distinction. It sounds like "one other" implies "the last one".  Correct?

Comment: If I had introduced someone to (say) five people, and all handshaking, etc, was finished, and we had left that group, and there was one other person I wanted them to meet, I would probably say it that way.

Comment: 'One other' is specific, 'another' is not.